# Elementary Number Theory: If $p$ and $a$ are natural numbers with prime $p$, and $p^4|a^3$, then $p^2|a$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm reviewing the basic number theory from my undergrad program (so I can jump back into abstract algebra well enough), and I've come across this problem in the section regarding the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. I'm sure the answer is sitting right in front of my face, but I can't figure out if I'm having an issue of not seeing the last step or going down the wrong path in the first place. Any help is appreciated; thanks!

*Prove:* Let $a,p\in\mathbb{N}$ with $p$ prime. If $p^4|a^3$, then $p^2|a$.

*Proof (so far):* Let $a,p\in\mathbb{N}$ be given, with $p$ prime, such that $p^4|a^3$. Then $p|a^3$, so by Euclid's Lemma, $p|a$, and thus $a=pn$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p^4k=a^3=ap^2n^2$, so $p^2\frac{k}{n^2}=a$. (Here's where I'm stuck; it would be great if I knew $n^2|k$)

Comment: From what you have, can you get that $ p \mid n$? If yes, do you see why $ p^2 \mid a$

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm not sure you could necessarily conclude that $p|n$. I can see how that would imply $p^2|a$, though.

Comment: You have $ p^4 \mid a^3 = p^3 n^3$. Can you conclude that $ p \mid n$?

Comment: Ah, I see.

$p^4k=p^3n^3$, so $pk=n^3$, and thus $p|n$ by Euclid's Lemma. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way

Let the highest exponent of prime $p$ that divides $a$ is $n$

So, the highest exponent of $p$ that divides $a^3$ will be $3n$

We need $3n\ge4\implies n\ge \dfrac43$

As $n$ is an integer, $n\ge2$